# JavaScript Leaflet Maps: marker icon is sometimes empty

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I'm using a LocationIQ map service: https://locationiq.com/docs and loading the 3 scripts in my page header (in concrete5 CMS controller):

```
$this->addHeaderItem($html->css("https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"));
$this->addHeaderItem($html->javascript("https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"));
$this->addHeaderItem($html->javascript("https://tiles.unwiredmaps.com/js/leaflet-unwired.js"));
```

and when I reload the page, sometimes the marker is empty, I checked the path to the marker icon is local, e.g.

```
<img src="http://localhost/c585/index.php/images/marker-icon.png"...
```

but sometimes the marker loads correctly and the marker icon image path is correct, e.g.

```
<img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png"...
```

What's causing the marker icon not to load correctly?

Comment: Can you try what happens to the Leaflet Layers Control icon as well?

Comment: Do you mean to the 'Streets' control icon? The map doesn't load because of that JS error, so there's no control icon there. But when it loads, it's a white square, when I hover over it, it shows a 'streets' radio button input.

Comment: Sounds like something copies the CSS into your server, but does not handle associated resources (typically images). I do not know how your concrete5 CMS is supposed to work; it might cause such issue. If there is an SO tag for it, you should probably add it.